# How do I use the PostgreSQL EXTRACT() function in a Glue ETL Job?

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue

I am using a Glue ETL Job to run a SQL query against a PostgreSQL database and write to S3 in parquet format. I am trying to use the `EXTRACT()` function to calculate the difference between two dates, but it is not working. Based on my testing, it appears the `EXTRACT()` function is not supported by some part of the Glue job.

Is the PostgreSQL `EXTRACT()` function supported in Glue ETL Jobs? If yes, how do I use it? If no, what specific technology does not support it? How can I identify other features that are supported/unsupported? Is there an alternative for calculating a date difference in PostgreSQL that *is* supported?

## Minimal Reproducible Example

Create a table with some dummy data:

```sql
create table my_table(id int, timestamp timestamp)
insert into my_table(id, timestamp)
values
    (1, '2024-01-22'),
    (2, '2024-01-23'),
    (3, '2024-01-24')
```

Glue ETL Script:

```py
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue import DynamicFrame

def spark_sql_query(glue_context, query, mapping, transformation_ctx) -> DynamicFrame:
    for alias, frame in mapping.items():
        frame.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView(alias)
    result = spark.sql(query)
    return DynamicFrame.fromDF(result, glue_context, transformation_ctx)

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME"])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)

my_table = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    connection_type="postgresql",
    connection_options={
        "useConnectionProperties": "true",
        "dbtable": "public.my_table",
        "connectionName": "my_db_connection",
    },
    transformation_ctx="my_table",
)

sql_query = "select id, timestamp from my_table"

source = spark_sql_query(
    glueContext,
    query=sql_query,
    mapping={
        'my_table': my_table
    },
    transformation_ctx="source",
)

target = glueContext.getSink(
    path="s3://my-bucket/data/test/",
    connection_type="s3",
    updateBehavior="UPDATE_IN_DATABASE",
    partitionKeys=[],
    enableUpdateCatalog=True,
    transformation_ctx="target",
)
target.setCatalogInfo(
    catalogDatabase="my-database", catalogTableName="test"
)
target.setFormat("glueparquet", compression="snappy")
target.writeFrame(source)
job.commit()
```

This works fine. However, if I change the SQL query to this:

```sql
select id, extract(epoch from timestamp) as result from my_table
```

Then I get the following error:

> Error Category: QUERY_ERROR; AnalysisException: Literals of type 'epoch' are currently not supported for the timestamp type.

Both SQL queries work fine when I query the PostgreSQL database directly, so it appears to be a problem with Glue, not PostgreSQL.